# How to hide one item(Button) and show another item(Button) from menu (Buttons in ActionBar) in single Activity

Tags: android, button, menu, android-actionbar

[image]

As attached in screenshot when I click on edit button then i want to hide edit button and show save button. How can i do that?

My menu file is as below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/edit_button"
    android:icon="@drawable/edit_button"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="@string/edit"/> 

</menu>
```

Is it possible this with image as edit to another image as save when button is clicked once and as save to edit when button is clicked again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    {

            if(editing){
                   item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_save);
            }else{
                   item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_edit);
            }   


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menu);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to change title because edit button is an image...So i want to change image with save button instead of edit button when edit button clicked.

Answer (score 1):

```
final DatePicker dp2 = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePick2);
final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate2);

dp2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
dp2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

btn2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

or

```
btn2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

when need visible:

```
btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

or you use Invisible or Gone, but not both!

Comment: This might be help me..but i am taking items as button from menu as in actionBar..So is it correct? In which method do i write this:final DatePicker dp2 = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePick2);
final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDate2);

dp2.setVisibility(View.GONE);    .......    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, you need other than asked.

Make not relevant, but change the

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit_button"
```

to

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/edit_or_save_button"
```

From the name you should know what will be the next:

if you press the button when it was an Edit, than you will do stuff in the activity which allows editing your data, but this button will change his text ( and action) to Save!

Of course you will assign different action listener, which will do the validation and save action.

If you really want to stick with 2 button idea  (highly disagree with that) :

```
Button edit_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.edit_button);
Button save_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_button);
```

...

```
edit_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        edit_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        save_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        DoEdit(v);
    }
});


 save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        save_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        edit_button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        DoValidationAndSave(v);
    }
});
```

I hope it solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
public boolean checkHide = false
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch(item.getItemId()){
        case EDIT:
            if(checkHide){
                checkHide=false;
                item.setTitle("edit");
                  // ToDo your function

                }
            else{
                checkHide=true;
                item.setTitle("save");
                  // ToDo your function
                 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to change title because edit button is an image...So i want to change image with save button instead of edit button when edit button clicked.